# Random files keep reappearing on phone memory

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lenovo

I've bought a Lenovo a6010 a few months ago and after a while, on the phone memory files keep reappearing even after deletion.

My question is, is it something to do with the amazingness of Lenovo's modified os, or is there an app that just doesn't know how to and where to put its files. If it is an app how can I trace and see what exactly made it this way?

Thanks for your time.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is name of folder where are this files are located?

Comment: Internal memory, /storage/sdcard0 or /sdcard (they link to the same folder). No other folders, that's why it is disturbing.

Comment: What is size of files try to open them with some text editor

Comment: Opening with an editor shows me machine language. (in other words lots of null and all that stuff).
The amount of files is exactly 100.
The size of the files in total is 11.26MB.  One file being around 52.73KB.
The most disturbing fact is not the size but the amount that floods in the home folder.

Comment: That's shame I tought maybe files will contain something usefull to determinate which app is creating them. So because sd card is world readable you can trace files back to apps, UID and GID will allways be the same for all apps. You can only try deleting one app and those files and then check if they are back. Try that if you have some not so famous apps. Edit: Mybe, just maybe some game creates this files because of ads or such things.

Comment: Games and ads, or who knows what, those things are ugly xD
We'll see what I can do about it, thanks for your time.